# Is it possible to use mysql 5.6's encrypted CNF files with mysqli or PDO in php?

Tags: php, mysql

Mysql 5.6 let's you created encrypted cnf files using [mysql-config-editor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html).

I was hoping to use that for a mysql connection in php.  The current script is using the mysqli library.

To be clear, this has nothing to do with connecting over SSL, simply being able to use the encrypted credential files generated by mysql-config-editor.

Answer (score 1):

I am not answering your question but i am suggesting you. It isn't big deal to see the user & password from .mylogin.cnf encrypted file. You can So You can use alternative way-

If you have access to the login.cnf (like .mylogin.cnf unencrypted format) via PHP you could use [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) to open and read it.

It should allow you to put the different sections directly into an associative array.

Something like this:

```
$settings = parse_ini_file('/path/to/login.cnf',true);
```

Now you can connect to mysql by using $settings.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what I'm going with.  Just make sure the cnf isn't world readable.  Just figured I'd explore the possibility for an extra layer since it exists.

Comment: further you can set permissions for more

Comment: Where does one put/find a `login.cnf` file?

Comment: @abeger generally it is in users home directory, you can also put any where & rename.